# Switch from electric range to gas range

Tags: drywall, valve, natural-gas

I’m think about buying a gas range and not sure if my kitchen is setup for it for or not.[image]

Comment: Open up that 'access panel' to the right of the outlet.  Maybe you'll get lucky!

Comment: If you have an unfinished basement the cost of having a pipe run is unlikely to be prohibitive.

Comment: This is impossible to answer sensibly. No clue as to where in the world . A detatched house or in a tower block? Please be way more specific. What makes you use 'valve' and 'natural gas'?

Answer (score 2):

A gas range needs a gas pipe. I'm not seeing one in that photo.   How hard it will be to install a gas pipe depends on how your house is constructed and whether or not you already have a gas supply to it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the picture, it does not appear that you are set up for a gas range. There are three things you need:

#### Electricity

Yes, you need electricity for a modern gas range. This is the easiest part. Typically, this requires a simple 120V 15A receptacle. There may be one available, but if not then it is possible to change the existing receptacle **and the breaker it is connected to** to give you a 120V 15A or 20A circuit in place of the existing 240V circuit. As a bonus, you can likely get another 120V circuit at minimal extra cost to use for countertop appliances.

#### Gas

There is no indication that gas is available in the necessary location. Assuming gas is in your home already, that can be anything from very easy (gas line immediately below the kitchen for furnace/hot water heater, like I have) to moderately hard (accessible area below but gas line only on the other side of the house) to prohibitively expensive (concrete slab below with no crawl space or access to run a gas line without tearing apart 1/2 the house). No way to guess from a picture of the kitchen. There is also a small possibility that you have a gas line and it is maxed out as far capacity.

#### Venting

All cooktops/ranges need venting, preferably to the outside. For an electric cooktop, this is primarily for smoke/smells. For gas there is an additional real safety issue of carbon monoxide. While a recirculating vent (or none at all, though that is not to code) is functional for electric, with gas you really do need a functioning vent/exhaust fan to the outside. That should be pretty obvious when looking at the kitchen, but it is not clear in the picture.